# Динамическое создание кнопок через определенное время

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне надо что бы по нажатию кнопки ежесекундно появлялась новая кнопка и так 10 кнопок.

Вот код для создания динамических кнопок по клику кнопки

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            buttonDyn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button(); // создаем контрол
            buttonDyn.Location =
                new System.Drawing.Point(100, 20 + i * 23); // устанавливаем необходимые свойства
            buttonDyn.Name = "button_Name_" + i;
            buttonDyn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 23);
            buttonDyn.TabIndex = 0;
            buttonDyn.Text = i.ToString();
            buttonDyn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            Controls.Add(buttonDyn);
        }
    }
```

Но он не работает, вместо ежесекундного появления новой кнопки просто через 10 секунд появляется 10 кнопок. В чем ошибка?

Comment: В том, что Вы заняли основной поток и не даете уже созданным кнопкам отрисоваться. Используйте таймер.

Comment: @Igor что за таймер? Thread.Sleep() не подходит?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx Вы же сами написали, что `Thread.Sleep()` Вас не устраивает. (И Ваших пользователей, я думаю, тоже.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот это

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Останавливает весь UI поток и не дает окну перерисоваться, пока весь цикл не закончится. Попробуйте создавать кнопки асинхронно

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        buttonDyn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button(); // создаем контрол
        buttonDyn.Location =
            new System.Drawing.Point(100, 20 + i * 23); // устанавливаем необходимые свойства
        buttonDyn.Name = "button_Name_" + i;
        buttonDyn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 23);
        buttonDyn.TabIndex = 0;
        buttonDyn.Text = i.ToString();
        buttonDyn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        Controls.Add(buttonDyn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Как то странно студия выделяет Delay в строке await Task.Delay(1000); красным, хотя using System.Threading.Tasks; стоит. Причем даже есть пример в MSDN правда с консолью.

Comment: @polsok выделяет красным и что то пишет при этом в ошибках? private **async** void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) - async не забыли указать?

Comment: оказывается проблема была что у меня нет 4.0 стоял